# long list selector with json does not working

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

i have a trouble wiht long list selector...i am populating a list by a json webservice and when a set  IsGroupingEnabled="true" the list isnt showing...if i change to  IsGroupingEnabled="false" the list show correctly but wont appears the letters grouped...

this is my code

XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="PhoneApp4.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"

SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Width="150" 
                           Height="150" 
                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           Grid.Column="0" 
                           Source="{Binding foto1}"
                           Margin="10" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top">
                </Image>

                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" 
                               Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
                               FontSize="20" 
                               Text="{Binding nome}" 
                               Grid.Row="1" 
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                <Button x:Name="gps" 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Height="75" 
                            Content="GPS" 
                            Click="gps_Click"
                            Margin="90"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListGroupHeaderTemplate">
        <Border  Padding="5">
            <Border  BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="2" Width="62" 
     Height="62" Margin="0,0,18,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" FontSize="48" Padding="6" 
        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
    <phone:JumpListItemForegroundConverter x:Key="ForegroundConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="ListJumpListStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
        <Setter Property="GridCellSize"  Value="113,113"/>
        <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="Grid" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border  Width="113" Height="113" Margin="6" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="48" Padding="6" 
           Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--header-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Red" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Teste" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="36"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--LongListSelecttor binding with friends informations-->

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,0,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector
            ItemsSource="{Binding listaws}"
              x:Name="lbResultado"
              JumpListStyle="{StaticResource ListJumpListStyle}"
              GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ListGroupHeaderTemplate}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListTemplate}"
              LayoutMode="List"
              IsGroupingEnabled="True"                
              HideEmptyGroups ="False" 
            />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MAINPAGE.XAML.C$

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using PhoneApp4;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace PhoneApp4
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        List<Wsempresa> ListaWs = new List<Wsempresa>();
        private const string DRIVING_PROTOCOL = "ms-drive-to";
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           // myButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(myButton_Click);
            SortingListAZ();
            string URL = "http://qualamelhormarca.com.br/novapasta/wsempresas.php";
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(URL, UriKind.Absolute));

            //LayoutRoot.Opacity = 0.5;
            lbResultado.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //List<Wsempresa> listaws = new List<Wsempresa>();
            //List<AlphaKeyGroup<Wsempresa>> list = AlphaKeyGroup<Wsempresa>.CreateGroups(listaws, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, c => c.nome, true);
            //lbResultado.ItemsSource = list; 
        }
        //void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    string URL = "http://192.168.1.4/QualAMelhorMarca/Divulguefranca/controller/wsempresas.php";

        //    WebClient client = new WebClient();
        //    client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        //    client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(URL, UriKind.Absolute));

        //    LayoutRoot.Opacity = 0.5;
        //    lbResultado.IsEnabled = false;

        //   // busca.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        //    myButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        //    //txtbusca.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        //    // pesquisar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;



        //}
        private void SortingListAZ()
        {
            List<AlphaKeyGroup<Wsempresa>> DataSource = AlphaKeyGroup<Wsempresa>.CreateGroups(ListaWs,
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
                (Wsempresa s) => { return s.nome; }, true);

            lbResultado.ItemsSource = DataSource;

        }
        void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer json =
                new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Wsempresa));
            Wsempresa lista = (Wsempresa)json.ReadObject(e.Result);

            ObservableCollection<Wsempresa> wsempresa = new ObservableCollection<Wsempresa>();
            try
            {
                // var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wsempresa>(e.Result);
                Wsempresa root = (Wsempresa)json.ReadObject(e.Result);
                if (wsempresa.Count != 0)
                {
                    wsempresa.Clear();
                }
                foreach (Wsempresa wsempresas in root.wsempresas)
                {
                    Wsempresa list = wsempresas;
                    wsempresa.Add(list);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            this.lbResultado.ItemsSource = wsempresa;
           // lbResultado.ItemsSource = wsempresa;
           // lbResultado.ItemsSource = lista.wsempresas;

          //  LayoutRoot.Opacity = 1;
            lbResultado.IsEnabled = true;
        }
            [DataContract(Name = "wsempresa")]
        public class Wsempresa
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "nome")]
            public string nome { get; set; }
                [DataMember(Name = "foto1")]
            public string foto1 { get; set; }
                [DataMember(Name = "telefone_comercial")]
            public string telefone_comercial { get; set; }
                [DataMember(Name = "latitude")]
            public string latitude { get; set; }
                [DataMember(Name = "longitude")]
            public string longitude { get; set; }

                [DataMember(Name = "wsempresas")]
                public Wsempresa[] wsempresas { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Wsempresa> wsempresas { get; set; }
        }



        void gps_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Wsempresa wsempresa = (Wsempresa)((Button)sender).DataContext;
            string latitude = wsempresa.latitude;
            string longitude = wsempresa.longitude;
            string nome = wsempresa.nome;


            string uriProtocol = null;
            string uri;

            // Driving or walking directions?
            string buttonClicked = ((Button)sender).Name;
            switch (buttonClicked)
            {
                case "gps":
                    uriProtocol = DRIVING_PROTOCOL;
                    break;
                default:
                    uriProtocol = DRIVING_PROTOCOL;
                    break;
            }

            // Assemble the Uri for the request.
            uri = uriProtocol + ":?" +
                "destination.latitude=" + latitude + "&" +
                "destination.longitude=" + longitude + "&" +
                "destination.name=" + nome;


            // Make the request.
            RequestDirections(uri);
        }

        async void RequestDirections(string uri)
        {
            // Make the request.
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri));
            if (success)
            {
                // Request succeeded.
            }
            else
            {
                // Request failed.
            }
        }



    }

}
```

AlphaKeyGroup.c$

```
   using Microsoft.Phone.Globalization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PhoneApp4
{
    public class AlphaKeyGroup<T> : List<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// O delegate que é usado para obter a informação da chave
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">Um objeto do tipo T</param>
        /// <returns>O valor da chave usado para esse objeto</returns>
        public delegate string GetKeyDelegate(T item);

        /// <summary>
        /// A chave deste grupo
        /// </summary>
        public string Key { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construtor público
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        public AlphaKeyGroup(string key)
        {
            Key = key;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cria uma lista de AlphaKeyGroup<T> com chaves "setadas" por um SortedLocaleGrouping
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="slg"></param>
        /// <returns>Fonte de dados para o LongListSelector</returns>
        private static List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> CreateGroups(SortedLocaleGrouping slg)
        {
            List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> list = new List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>>();

            foreach (string key in slg.GroupDisplayNames)
            {
                list.Add(new AlphaKeyGroup<T>(key));
            }

            return list;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cria uma lista de AlphaGroup<T> com as chaves "setadas" por um SortedLocaleGrouping
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items">Os itens a serem colocados em grupo</param>
        /// <param name="ci">A CultureInfo para ordenar e agrupar</param>
        /// <param name="getKey">Um delegate para pegar a chave de um item</param>
        /// <param name="sort">Irá ordenar os dados se for "true"</param>
        /// <returns>Uma fonte de dados para o LongListSelector</returns>
        public static List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> CreateGroups(IEnumerable<T> items, CultureInfo ci, GetKeyDelegate getKey, bool sort)
        {
            SortedLocaleGrouping slg = new SortedLocaleGrouping(ci);
            List<AlphaKeyGroup<T>> list = CreateGroups(slg);

            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                int index = 0;
                if (slg.SupportsPhonetics)
                {
                    //index = slg.GetGroupIndex(getKey(Yomiof(item)));
                }
                else
                {
                    index = slg.GetGroupIndex(getKey(item));
                }
                if (index >= 0 && index < list.Count)
                {
                    list[index].Add(item);
                }
            }
            if (sort)
            {
                foreach (AlphaKeyGroup<T> group in list)
                {
                    group.Sort((c0, c1) => { return ci.CompareInfo.Compare(getKey(c0), getKey(c1)); });
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I ve made this question on msdn forum, and the answer is my json does not returned data from your JSON call. 
But i sendo some sreenshot of my phone showing my json working corectly with IsGroupingEnabled="False", if i change to true the list dont appear.
 the sreenshot is here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b3074356-7924-42b4-bdd0-c2d5a8861d77/longlistselector-not-working-with-isgroupingenabledtrue?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem is in client_OpenReadCompleted.

In your code there is

```
this.lbResultado.ItemsSource = wsempresa;
```

and so on.

Instead of that you should set

```
ListaWs = wsempresa;
SortingListAZ();
```

Comment: just changed the lines that u mentioned and is giving this error in wsempresa Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<PhoneApp4.MainPage.Wsempresa>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PhoneApp4.MainPage.Wsempresa>' D:\Projetos WP\PhoneApp4\PhoneApp4\MainPage.xaml.cs 99 23 PhoneApp4
have any more change?

Comment: Yes, I didn't mentioned that. That's because ListaWs is not observableCollection, even though wsempresa is. I recommend you to change ListaWs type to observablecollection. On other hand you can change wsempresa type to List.

Comment: I changed the ListaWs to ObservableCollection and showed no more error, however when running the app shows nothing, the list does not appear and also shows the grouped letters ... have any tips?

Comment: So letters are showing, but there is no items? I would need the json to check what's going on. Your code doesn't return me anything, so I can't test the program. Can you descripe a short example of your json? I could then simulate your program.

Comment: with the changes that u asked to do only appears a blank list with gps button I put in each list item ... my json on this link that shows the code http://qualamelhormarca.com.br/novapasta/wsempresas.php.

Comment: but if you need this here it {"wsempresas":[{"nome":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","foto1":"http:\/\/wowbsb.files.wordpress.com\/2011\/08\/panda-xpress-1600x1200.jpg","telefone_comercial":"(16) 3724-7100","latitude":"-20.549620","longitude":"-47.396966"}]}

Comment: Well, it works in my phone. Are you sure that you have IsGroupingEnabled = true in your xaml?

Comment: on my phone only shows 4 squares (4 registers in json) but dont show the images and texts from json...can u take a screenshot for me?

Comment: Where do you need a screenshot?? With those two changes I was able to see images, names and gps buttons in four squares.

Comment: There's lines I changed:
`List<Wsempresa> ListaWs = new List<Wsempresa>();` -->  `ObservableCollection<Wsempresa> ListaWs = new ObservableCollection<Wsempresa>();`

 and
 
  `this.lbResultado.ItemsSource = wsempresa;` -->
  `ListaWs = wsempresa;
  SortingListAZ();`